# NuxtJs deployed with docker using traefik PathPrefix won't detect page

Tags: javascript, docker, routes, nuxt.js, traefik

We have blog in a NuxtJs project deployed using docker and traefik's `PathPrefix('/blog')` so instead of being served from https://example.com/  is served from
https://example.com/blog/

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  {{ project_id }}-awesome-blog-{{ awesome_blog_env }}:
    # etc.. 
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.awesome_blog-{{ awesome_blog_env }}-router.rule=Host(`{{ awesome_blog_host_dns }}`) && PathPrefix(`/blog`)
    # etc..
      - {{ docker_network }}

networks:
  {{ docker_network }}:
    external: true
```

The issue is that because of the `PathPrefix` Nuxt does not seem to know the actual page. As it's receiving `/blog/` as `path` it doesn't match any expected route

this is what `this.$router` prints out in the server on the server from https://example.com/blog/

```
{
  "name": null,
  "meta": {},
  "path": "/blog/",
  "hash": "",
  "query": {},
  "params": {},
  "fullPath": "/blog/",
  "matched": []
}
```

And this is what it prints in local from http://localhost.com:3000/

```
{
  "name": "index___en",
  "meta": {},
  "path": "/",
  "hash": "",
  "query": {},
  "params": {},
  "fullPath": "/",
  "matched": [{
    //...etc
    name: "index___en",
    // ..etc
  }]
}
```

I tried using the

```
router: {
   base: '/blog/
}
```

Which in local works but in the server seems not to work (doesn't even get to the nuxt site and printing the server 404)

As an "ugly" alternative I tried copying all the pages inside the /blog/ folder and they do respond but my serverMiddleware does not (returns 404)

this serverMiddleware is setup like this:

nuxt.config.js

```
serverMiddleware: ['~/server-middleware/index.js'],
```

server-middleware/index.js

```
const nocache = require('nocache');
const express = require('express')
const buildRouter = require('../server/router.js')

const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
app.use(nocache());
buildRouter(app)

module.exports = app
```

server/router.js

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  const buildApiRoute = require('./controllers/api')
  buildApiRoute(app, '/api')
}
```

Tried with /blog/api, too

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  const buildApiRoute = require('./controllers/api')
  buildApiRoute(app, '/blog/api')
}
```

Anyways, is there any way to tell nuxt to ignore the `/blog/` slug of the url o something similar?

Magic code

```
// Before anything
this.$router.fullPath = this.$router.fullpath.replace('/blog', '/')
this.$router.path = this.$router.path.replace('/blog', '/')
```